# Find and replace text and wrap in "href"

Tags: string, replace, find, href

I am trying to find specific word in a div (id="Test") that starts with "a04"     (no case). I can find and replace the words found.  But I am unable to     correctly use the word found in a "href" link.

I am trying the following working code that correctly identifies my search     criteria. My current code is working as expected but I would like help as i do not know how to used the found work as the url id?

```
var test = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML
function replacetxt(){
    var str_rep = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML.replace(/a04(\w)+/g,'<a href="">TEST</a>');
    var temp = str_rep;
    //alert(temp);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = temp;
}
```

I would like to wrap the found word in an href but i do not know how to use the found word as the url id (url.com?id=found word).

Can someone help point out how to reference the found work please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your pattern with the capturing group, you could move the quantifier `+` inside the group or else you would only get the value of the last iteration.

```
\ba04(\w+)
```

- `\b` word boundary to prevent the match being part of a longer word
- `a04` Match literally
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times a word character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8HIZ8/1)

Then you could use the first capturing group in the replacement by referring to it with `$1`

If the string is `a04word`, you would capture `word` in group 1.

Your code might look like:

```js
function replacetxt(){
    var elm = document.getElementById("test");
    if (elm) {
        elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML.replace(/\ba04(\w+)/g,'<a href="url.com?id=$1">TEST</a>');
    }
}

replacetxt();
```

```html
<div id="test">This is text a04word more text here</div>
```

**Note** that you don't have to create extra variables like `var temp = str_rep;`

Comment: Great thanks for the assist.   One question how does "$1" reference 'word'?

Comment: It is the first capturing group in the pattern and references what is between parenthesis.

Comment: @Alsjka I have updated the pattern with a word boundary and added an explanation to it.